# CORS issue when trying to log to Azure AD with ionic app

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth, active-directory

I'm working with Node, Express & Ionic to create an Azure AD auth system.
I'm using `passportjs` and `passport-azure-ad`

When I try to log using my back-end, everything works fine, but when calling from the front I get :

> Failed to load
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/...:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGJFAfvhQZg&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jdm7QX143aMLAqyM-jTZ2x&index=14) to set `passport` up

Here are the routes in the back :

```
router.get('/auth/openid/return', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'), function(req, res, next) {

    res.send(req.user);
});

router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'));
```

Here is `passport` setup:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    // user et le resultat que tu as mis dans les autres done en dessous
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    dbConsumer.findByPrimaryId(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user)
    });
});

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
    // TODO ne pas commiter ces infooooooos
    clientID: "correct clientId",
    clientSecret: "correct client secret",
    identityMetadata: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/constellationdemo.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    responseType: "code",
    responseMode: "query",
    redirectUrl: "https://localhost:3000/azure/auth/openid/return",
    passReqToCallback: false
},
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // look for the user
        dbConsumer.findByAzureId(profile.oid).then(user => {
           if(user.rowCount > 0){
               logger.log({
                   level: 'info',
                   message: profile.displayName + "already exists"
               });
               // On passe un user pour qu'il reconnaisse le user dans le serializer au dessus
               done(null, user.rows[0]);
           }
           else {
               dbConsumer.insertUserProvider(profile.displayName, profile.oid).then(data => {
                   if(data.success) {
                       logger.log({
                           level: 'info',
                           message: "User: " + profile.displayName + "inserted"
                       });
                       // On passe un user pour qu'il reconnaisse le user dans le serializer au dessus
                       done(null, data.newUser);
                   }
               }).catch(err => {
                   logger.log({
                       level: 'error',
                       message: err
                   });
               });
           }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("dans l err");
            console.log(err);
        });
}))
```

Here is my front service :

```
initHeaders() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length");

    return headers;
  }

  logToAzure() {
    return this.http.get(this.domain + 'azure/login', {headers: this.initHeaders()})
  }
```

When i check the request in the console, none of the headers are set.

I've also enabled cors in the back;

I need help

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with some apis with angular. If you use chrome try to use this chrome app **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin**

[image: Reference image enable cors with Allow-Control-Allow-Origin]

When you enable cors, some apis don't respond (sign in services, youtube video streaming, and google drive does not work properly so be careful with this)